# Can I write a script that pulls batch contact info from a website?

Tags: html, text, batch-file

I'm doing a project for my job and am trying to get attorneys contact information off of the GA bar website. I've searched for programs to do it, but am not finding anything for exactly what I need.

I need to get all of the attorneys information into excel and I figured there was some batch text program to do the job. There are over 50,000 contacts listed and I really dont think I need to click on every link to view the information to be able to access it.

I have opened up the code on the page with "inspect element" on chrome and saw that each attorney has a unique ID on the site. I feel like their info can easily be copied from the site, but I have very limited programming knowledge.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we get site link or example of site link to see what language website is based on or type of data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to check the terms of service / copyright of the GA bar website and make sure you are allowed to do that.

Before you start coding, you may consider requesting the contact info in database format.  The information may be available for free, or for a fee that is less than the cost of you programming a solution.

If you must program, a very capable library for scraping the contents of a website is [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  I suggest you become familiar with it, and post more detailed questions here as you get into specifics.

HTML Agility Pack does require programming.  If you're looking for a non-programming solution, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask.